# Java library to create PDF file

Tags: gratis, library, java, pdf

I am looking for a free library to create and export PDF files.

I will receive StringBuilder like that:

```
value;timestamp
8627;1514674800000;
8627;1514761200000;
```

and I need to generate and export to an user PDF file.

Comment: You can explore this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355025/create-pdf-with-java and http://www.baeldung.com/java-pdf-creation

Comment: I tried it before however it is really primitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free or nearly free PDF library for Java](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/free-or-nearly-free-pdf-library-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below APIs for creating and exporting PDF files from Java -

1. Apache PDFBox
2. BFO
3. iText

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Open Lowcode](https://openlowcode.com/) PDF (disclaimer: I am the author of this framework).

A first pre-production version was just released today on [github](https://github.com/openlowcode/Open-Lowcode/releases/tag/PDF-v0.1.0). Feel free to have a look and provide feedback.

THe library aims at creating quickly forms and corporate documents.

The library is free and open-source, and also appropriate to incorporate in proprietary product (using Eclipse license).